# What is the difference between window based and view based iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the difference between window based and view based iphone apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From xcode:

The **window based** template provides a starting point for any application. It provides just an application delegate and a window.

This **view based** template provides a starting point for an application that uses a single view. It provides a view controller to manage the view, and a nib file that contains the view.

Comment: Of course, these are just templates though, they don't limit how the application can expand or grow once you start developing. One could take the Window template and effectively turn it into an app that uses a single view with a view controller, just as a view based app could be turned into an app with multiple views and view controllers. The templates are just convenience to setup things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what has already been said, the most important thing to remember is that iPhone apps can only deal with just a window. Therefore, you will always have a single window, even though you may have as many views (and corresponding view controllers) as your app needs.